# Does Kali installed through WSL respect my privacy?

Tags: privacy, kali-linux, microsoft, wsl

When installing Kali from Microsoft Store, I wasn't prompted with a user agreement license.

Is Microsoft able to monitor my applications? How safe is it to use [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) in that context? (From privacy perspective)

Comment: Why are you expecting a user license agreement for something that Microsoft does not own or control? How is a license related to "being able to monitor my applications"? Windows 10 has all kinds of telemetry. Are you asking besides those functions?

Comment: @schroeder Yes, but your comment makes me think that they're not able to monitor me. I'm not that much familiar with their products, for the most part I've been using Linux based systems, so you may understand from where my concern arises.

Comment: Basically, the question is, "I downloaded software from somewhere I do not trust. Can I trust it anyway?". If you do not sufficiently trust Microsoft, do not download from their store. It is really as simple as that. There are plenty of other sources for Kali.

Comment: It's not the source I don't trust. 
It's the context in which I do not trust it, since penetration tests are quite sensitive.

Comment: Microsoft knows every executable you have on your Windows system via Defender. It will be scanned, hashed, categorized, and copied for analysis if unknown.

Comment: @user10216038 That raises a legal issue where a developed software, a private property is being sent to a third-party. May we confirm this behavior?

Comment: I think you'll find that you agreed to all this as part of Microsoft allowing you to use their systems. You didn't buy it and you don't own it, you're allowed to use it. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/servicesagreement "... **you grant to Microsoft a worldwide and royalty-free intellectual property license to use Your Content** ..."

Comment: I'm going to uninstall it.

Comment: This is fascinating that Microsoft is now requiring a license to any content you generate on their systems (and some other rather onerous restrictions on use of their services).  It makes me less and less inclined to ever use a MS product.  Thanks for this question.

Comment: You're welcome @SteveSether. It is scary to what the business model of software is becoming. Alternatives exist, I've switched to Ubuntu. Since I've the most experience with it, even more than the Windows.
What secondary distro would recommend me?

Comment: Why are you using Kali in WSL?  Kali Linux is usually the type of OS one would want to run with the least amount of virtualization involved.  The reason being that in real practice, Kali Linux is usually booted from a USB flash drive, when penetration testing a server or another enterprise device on the network.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments of this question, Windows has many telemetry features. Ones which you cannot disable, either. There are [some settings](https://pixelprivacy.com/resources/windows-privacy-settings/) you can change to reclaim **some** privacy but in general, you cannot remove all the tracking features. This makes it a horrible operating system as far as privacy is concerned.

Additionally, their service agreement effectively gives them control over any content you generate on their system. This is also terrible for both you and your privacy.

If you're concerned about your privacy then don't use Windows at all. It is a horrible OS in terms of privacy.